# Is there a repository of house CAD files that can be used for energy simulations?

Tags: architecture, simulation, cad, sketchup, energyplus

A bit of a niche question, but I'm looking for a repository of home construction CAD files that can be easily imported into building simulation software like EnergyPlus or TRNSYS. My goal is to be able to test HVAC control methods on a bunch of different building types without having to manual design each building. I've found https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/ but there's not a ton of normal buildings (most are expensive modern-style construction).

Answer (score 0):

The U.S. department of energy offers a database of prototype building models [(see link)](https://www.energycodes.gov/prototype-building-models) for EnergyPlus. They provide them as EnergyPlus idf files. If you need them inside CAD software you can use EnergyPlus to create DXF's from them.